# Class not found / wrong name when using wsgen

Tags: java, web-services, wsgen

I'm having an issue with `wsgen` and while I've seen some answers that worked none of those solutions seems to be working for me. I believe the problem is related to the structure of the source and binaries.

My `WSTest` project is setup with the following folders:

```
bin
└───com
    └───example
        └───ws
src
└───com
    └───example
        └───ws
```

The main class is `Test` which resides in package `com.example.ws`.

I'm running `wsgen` from the main project folder `WSTest` using the following command:

```
wsgen -cp ./bin/com/example/ws -d ./src/com/example/ws -s ./src/com/example/ws Test
```

This results in:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError (wrong name: com/example/ws/Test)

This makes sense since the class is part of a package.  So I change my command to the following:

```
wsgen -cp ./bin/com/example/ws -d ./src/com/example/ws -s ./src/com/example/ws com.example.ws.Test
```

But now I get class not found from the `wsgen` tool:

> Class not found: "com.example.ws.Test"
>
> Usage: WSGEN [options]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried something like this?

```
wsgen -cp ./bin -d ./src -s ./src com.example.ws.Test
```

The classpath folder is were `wsgen` looks for class files. The package within the class is resolved to folder paths, so `com.example.ws.Test` should be a file like `com/example/ws/Test.class` within the `bin` classpath folder.

From the [Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html):

> Each classpath should end with a filename or directory depending on what you are setting the class path to:
>
> - For a .jar or .zip file that contains .class files, the class path ends with the name of the .zip or .jar file.
> - For .class files in an unnamed package, the class path ends with the directory that contains the .class files.
> - For .class files in a named package, the class path ends with the directory that contains the "root" package (the first package in the full package name).